# Javascript Canvas draw rectangles or circles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rectangles

I'm searching for a way to "live" draw rectangles or circles on a canvas.

I found various ways with `fillRect()` to draw rectangles, but not live. What I mean is, to be able to `mouseDown()` on one point and move it to another point in the canvas, which defines the size of the canvas, just like for example in Microsoft Paint, OneNote and so on.

Can anybody help me out and give me an advice on how to get started? I might be thinking of a way on how to do it, without seeing the rectangle (or circle) size changing, something like:

```
 $("canvas").mousedown(function(event){
     var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,$(this).width(),$(this).height());
     var initialX = event.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left;
     var initialY = event.clientY - this.getBoundingClientRect().top;

     $(this).mousemove(function(evt) {
         ctx.strokeRect(initialX, initialY, evt.clientX - event.clientX, evt.clientY - event.clientY);
     });
 });
```

But I want to see it live, so how the rectangles size changes when the user moves the mouse.

Comment: use `window.requestAnimationFrame()` to refresh the canvas often

Comment: @randnum-1 and? you mean to redraw the canvas every 50ms or something like that in `setInterval()` until `mouseUp`?

Comment: I'm assuming you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/jk607fqn/3/ click on canvas to draw red square

Comment: to add to that, if you want something more sophisticated it would be better to do what randnum-1 suggests, and collect event data between frames then have a "render" routine that is called on an interval. On the other hand, you can get away with just using events if all you want is a throwaway page effect. I've updated the above now to handle some basic click and drag: https://jsfiddle.net/b8rq8u4f/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/zb66mxra/2/

To do it live you need to keep a constant image of your Canvas. This is accomplished easily by keeping an array of objects to be drawn over and over again by your JavaScript.

```
let drawArr = [];
```

An example object contains an x and y coordinate to begin drawing, a width, and a height:

```
 { x: 100,
  y: 100,
  w: 10,
  h: 10  }
```

when your mouse moves over the canvas you ONLY want it to change the array if the mouse is down. This means you need to set a flag to see if this case is either true or false:

```
  let mousedown = false;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    mousedown = true;
  ...
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
  });
```

When your mouse is down you want to add an item to draw to the array:

```
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  mousedown = true;
  drawArr.push({
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY,
    w: 0,
    h: 0
  });
});
```

The height and width are initially set to 0. What we want to do now, if you can imagine, is create a height and width of the rectangle while we're dragging the mouse over the canvas and the mouse is down. We want to adjust this on the fly so that when the screen is re-rendered it is seen as it's being drawn.

It's easy to manipulate the height and width because, as long as you're only able to draw one at a time, it will ALWAYS be the most recent object added to the draw array.

```
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (mousedown) {
    let i = drawArr.length -1;

    let {
      x,
      y
    } = drawArr[i];
    drawArr[i].w = e.pageX - x;
    drawArr[i].h = e.pageY - y;
  }
});
```

Finally we use requestAnimationFrame to constantly draw any object within the draw array. We do this by calling it when the page is loaded:

```
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

And then recursively within the draw function:

```
function draw() {
...
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Then we simply need to clear the previous screen render and iterate over the draw array and draw everything to the screen again.

```
  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    for (let obj of drawArr) {
    let {
      x,
      y,
      w,
      h
     } = obj;
      ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
```

voila.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks good and is exactly what I want, I will try it out as soon as possible, one question: Is it hard to draw a circle with code like that? So would it be a big change? So same principle, just with a circle

Comment: @nameless It would be very similar. You would need to use the arc context method followed by stroke() instead of strokeRect. You would also need to store a radius within your draw object and fiddle with updating it when dragging over the canvas.

Comment: https://medium.com/wdstack/quick-blurb-2d-canvas-app-setup-5e6f13e12884  This article I wrote awhile back may help you understand the basic methods and architecture of 2d canvas better. Also, if this is what you were looking for, please accept this answer by clicking the green checkbox next to it.

Comment: just tried to integrate it now, but it doesn't seem to be that easy for me... as in my canvas, you can already draw normally (like just moving the mouse to draw) and only when clicking on a button, you should be able to draw rectangles and then move back to normal lines, any advices on how to do that?

Comment: @nameless Well, if you're not storing the drawing information in an object array, you should be. I would suggest adding an additional key to each object that would allow the program to interpret how it should draw the object on the canvas. For instance type: circle, would use the arc method, type: square, the fillRect, type: line, the moveTo/lineTo methods ,etc.